# cannot log in to control panel after 2.9.2 update. credentials are being accepted

Tags: ee2

I just updated my EE install to 2.9.2 and cannot log into the control panel.

It is recognizing my username and password, but I am redirected back to the log-in page. If I enter bogus credentials, it lets me know either the username or password are incorrect.

I have tried adding the following to my config file as suggested across StackOverflow:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_path'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['user_session_type'] = 'c';
$config['admin_session_type'] = 's';
```

I have tried clearing caches and everything like that.

The oddest part is, I've tried logging in many times now. Seemingly randomly, it does allow me to log in (maybe 2 times out of 100 attempts), but as soon as I click anything in the CP, i am bumped back out to the log in screen.

Comment: A shot in the dark: are your third party add-ons up to date?

Answer (score 1):

for whatever reason, i had this line in my config.php file that was the culprit

```
$config['server_offset'] = '-60';
```